# How to take an array input from a formfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

I want to enter a array like [1,2,3,4,5] in the form field and use that form value as a parameter to bubblesort function to sort the array.How to implement this in flutter?

Comment: You might try parsing it as JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple and just use the builtin json parser.
Like this:

`List<int> nbs = List<int>.from(json.decode('[1,2,3,4]'));`

Answer (score 1):

Our string:

```dart
  final hi = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
```

The regular expression used to remove the square brackets:

```dart
  final regex = RegExp(r'([\[\]])');
```

Our string without any brackets after replacing them with nothing:

```dart
  final justNumbers = hi.replaceAll(regex, ''); // 1,2,3,4,5
```

Our list of strings by splitting them by commas:

```dart
  List<String> strings = justNumbers.split(',');
```

Now we parse our strings into integers (`tryParse` is used so that it returns `null` instead of throwing an exception):

```dart
  List<int> numbers = strings.map((e) => int.tryParse(e)).toList();
```

Final

```dart
void main() {
  final hi = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
  final regex = RegExp(r'([\[\]])');
  final justNumbers = hi.replaceAll(regex, '');
  List<String> strings = justNumbers.split(',');
  List<int> numbers = strings.map((e) => int.tryParse(e)).toList();
  print(numbers);
}
```